# How to insert calculated value with values from select query together?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 tables namely:

```
Table1 ( Sum, count, Name1, Address1, Zip1)
Table2 (Name, Address, Zip)
```

```
sum = 0;
for(int i=1; i<=10; i++)
{
    sum += i;
}
```

I have to insert the sum value after each iteration and also the value of 'i' to column Sum, count of Table 1 along with all columns of Table2.

```
Insert into Table1(Sum, count, Name1, Address1, Zip1)
Select * from Table2
```

Above is my SQL query how can insert the sum & count.

Comment: can you post the expected data?

Answer (score 1):

For Mysql 8.0+ you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` and `SUM()` window functions:

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (Sum, Count, Name1, Address1, Zip1)
SELECT SUM(t2.rn) OVER (ORDER BY t2.rn), 
       t2.rn, t2.Name, t2.Address, t2.Zip
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS rn FROM Table2) t2;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d87f61c9de09dca27a950fe836a5ab40).

For previous versions you can use variables to calculate `Count` and `Sum`:

```
SET @rownum:=0;
SET @sum:=0;
INSERT INTO Table1 (Count, Sum, Name1, Address1, Zip1)
SELECT @rownum:=(@rownum+1), @sum:=(@sum+@rownum),
       Name, Address, Zip
FROM Table2;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=be990b6f1885eef707238fba87d488e9).

But since the order of the evaluation of the variable columns is not guaranteed, it is better to use a nested subquery so you calculate the column `Sum` after `Count`:

```
SET @rownum:=0;
SET @sum:=0;
INSERT INTO Table1 (Sum, Count, Name1, Address1, Zip1)
SELECT @sum:=(@sum+t2.rn), 
       t2.rn, Name, Address, Zip
FROM (SELECT @rownum:=(@rownum+1) AS rn, Name, Address, Zip FROM Table2) t2;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=131b69b3e4a0c82f2ccdb55e1e900965).

Note that in all cases the order of the rows of `Table2` that are inserted in `Table1` is undefined.
If you want them inserted say sorted by `Name`, then an `ORDER BY` clause must be used in all queries.